# When can a function be represented by an infinite nested radical, a la a Taylor series?

Tags: analysis, generating-functions

Given a (let's say analytic) real function $f(x)$, when can $f(x)$ be represented as an infinite nested radical depending on $x$, constructed from some sequence? For example, the third and fourth pages of the following link (http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/ramanujanday.pdf) describe such a representation when $f(x) = 1 + x$.

Comment: After 19 posts over the period of two months, you don't have the "I'm new and don't know things here" excuse anymore. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You're right, but I don't think not knowing how to use MathJax detracted much from my formulation of this question. There's no need to downvote me-- I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: good question. not sure if the book modern analysis had anything related